# How to detect if the inputted string is on the list and if it is repeated?

Tags: python

I made a list where the user can avoid repeating answers. So I made a conditon. For every right answer of the user, the answers will be on the list.

```
index = 0
while index < 10:
    f = open('D:/VB/PRELIM/topic1.txt')
    text = f.read().strip().split()
    answer = []
    topic1 = ['SPIDER', 'HEIGHT', 'STRANGER', 'DYING', 'DARK','GHOST','SNAKE','ALONE','BOSS','FIRED'] 
    answerlst = input(str(index + 1) + '. ').upper()
    topic1_contains = any(topic1 in answerlst for topic1 in topic1) #check if the inputted answer is detected whenever they add 'S' in the end.
    
    if answerlst in text: #text is my filetext
        if answerlst in answer and topic1_contains: #check if the word is on file 
            print("You repeated your answer!")
    else:
            answer.append(answerlst)
            repeat = False
```

What I want to be like is for example, in first input, I inputted "Height", in my second input, "I inputted "Heights". In this, I want to meet the condition but it is not working.

Comment: `Height != Heights` -- there's an extra `s`.

Comment: 1. You might check if the input string ends on "s" and then check just for the pre string.
2. I would use a `set` instead of the `list` because searching for matches is much quicker

Comment: HEIGHTS

HEIGHT

I have these 2 in my text file. That's the possible answer of the user. I have a condition where if the answer found in text file. I made a list (topic1) to check if the word "heights" is the same as 'height". That's why I have an AND condition and I don't know why it is not working